# The tag-information for an excluded tag is shown in the search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

When you perform a search with an excluded tag, the tag information box appears.
For example, do a search on this meta site for ["unicorns -[discussion]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicorns%20-%5Bdiscussion%5D). At the top of the results page, the information box states:

> This tag indicates that the question may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.

Describing the tag that was explicitly excluded seems to be a bug.  I noticed this when searching on StackOverflow for ["layout -[HTML]"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=layout%20-%5Bhtml%5D). When I saw the HTML tag information box at the top of the page, I mistakenly assumed that I had used the wrong tag exclusion syntax.

Note that this does not happen when using two tags:  "[layout] -[HTML]" has no info box.

Answer (score 5):

Uhhhhhhhhhh, yeah I guess that shouldn't happen eh?

Fixed in the next build!